# Is putting the pronoun after the reporting verb ungrammatical and obsolete?

Tags: reported-speech

Hewings M. in his book *Advanced Grammar in Use* explains that in the English used in stories and novels, the *reporting verb* (e.g. **ask, continue**) is **often** placed before the subject when the *reporting clause* comes after the quotation **except** when the subject is a **pronoun**:

- 'And after that I moved to Italy,' she continued. (*not*... continued she)

However, I've seen otherwise in C.S. Lewis' book (*Narnia: The Magician's Nephew*) i.e. [reporting verb + pronoun] twice, thrice, or so.

> “It was rather hard luck on them, all the same,” **said he**.

> She flashed her horrible, wicked eyes upon me and said, ‘Victory.’
> ‘Yes,’ **said I**, ‘Victory, but not yours.’

Since I'm at chapter 6, I can't give examples other than the verb *say*. And as you have probably known that this book is old, that's the reason I'm asking whether it's obsolete or not. So, how is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that M. Hewings is correct on this.  While both versions are perfectly grammatical and understandable, it does seem that something like:

> "Blah blah blah," said Peter.
> "Yada yada," said he.

sounds slightly more *stilted* and indicative of an older generation of authors like C.S. Lewis, whereas:

> "Blah blah blah," said Harry.
> "Yada yada," he said.

sounds slightly more contemporary and indicative of authors like J.K. Rowling.

---

That isn't to say that an author cannot *choose* to use the "dated" version for a modern work, just that Hewings seems to be correct in his general outline of which version constitutes the contemporary default preference.

Though, in the grand scheme of things, adhering to one specific prescription doesn't seem particularly important.  I can easily imagine seeing a mix of "Harry said" and "said Harry" alongside "he said" and "said he" in contemporary works simply as a means to make long stretches of dialog feel less repetitive.